# spring security and oauth dependencies?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am confused what is the different between these dependencies and which one should I use. Would you explain the differences?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!---------------------------------------------------------->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!---------------------------------------------------------->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
        <!---------------------------------------------------------->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and when to use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring-boot-starter-xxx` are with no surprise starters for applications with Spring. It:

- pulls most the dependencies you need on a subject
- auto-wires many useful beans
- enables to define many configuration options from properties (application.properties, application.yaml, command line arguments, environment variables,...)

For OAuth2, there are two starters provided by Spring:

- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` if your app is a resource-server (contains `@RestController` or `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody`)
- `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` if your app is a client

  - `@Controller` with methods returning a template name
  - using a REST client like `WebClient` to consume a web-service secured with OAuth2

I also wrote starters which are thin wrappers arround `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and enable to replace all of necessary Java configuration with just a few properties. Refer to [README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) and [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for more details (and to figure out how much effort and errors it can save)

It is possible for an app to be both a resource-server and a client, in which case you'll need to declare both starters in your dependencies.

You can have a look at the tutorials I already linked if you have doubts on how to configure resource-servers. There are a few whith Spring starters or mine. One is even both a resource-server and a client with Thymeleaf page consuming secured REST resources with WebClient)

You don't need to declare dependencies on `spring-boot-starter-security`, `spring-security-oauth2-client` or `spring-security-oauth2-jose` when using OAuth2 starters as all are transitive dependencies.

`spring-security-config` is useful for defining Spring @Beans in Java configuration files. You might need it in addition to starters.